# Text width different across browsers

Tags: css, fonts, cross-browser

For a reason I need to get the width of the text. When I use offsetWidth, clientWidth or getBoundingClientRect, I do have differences in calculating the width of the text across different browsers, mainly in Edge.

I tried the following:
[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fwpxs8ac/4/)

```css
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 font-size: 100%;
 font: inherit;
 vertical-align: baseline;
}
body {
 line-height: 1;
}

h1 {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 38px;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
```

```html
<h1>Welk woord is onderstreept?</h1>
<script>
  var h1 = document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0];
  document.write(h1.offsetWidth);
</script>
```

It doesn't matter which font I use. Does anyone knows a proper solution to have the same width of text in every browser?

Comment: Different OS and different browser use different rendering engine for font so they can have different size.

Comment: Simply put, you can't, as each browser has its way to render the text, and on top, different OS, ...and nobody is gonna test cross browser to see how many pixels one or the other differs, and give you some penalty for that :) . And their difference is one reason why people chose one of them.

Comment: Hmm too bad, then I am pretty stuck, because text is gonna break now when the container has the width of the text width. Thanks anyway!